# Docker + Weave dns not resolving on other host

Tags: dns, docker, weave

I'm running docker and weave/weavedns, i'm having trouble connecting between the two hosts.

I'm running a container on host1, its pingable and the hostname resolves locally.

On host2, i can ping the container, but not resolve by its hostname. The weave logs indicate that the two hosts are definitely connected. The weavedns logs show ....

```
INFO: 2015/02/25 10:06:19.544828 [dns msgid 31446] No results for type A query rabbitmq01.weave.local.
DEBUG: 2015/02/25 10:06:19.545426 Query: {Name:rabbitmq01.weave.local. Qtype:1 Qclass:1}
DEBUG: 2015/02/25 10:06:19.545593 [mdns msgid 45925] No local answer for mDNS query rabbitmq01.weave.local.
```

... when I try to ping the hostname.

I've double checked that there is no IP conflicts on the weave network and the hosts are on the same subnet

Comment: I think this post should be moved to "Super User".

Comment: Im dealing with a similar problem. One thing I noticed is that you're using the full host name "host.weave.local" from within your container, when you should just be using "host" from within your container. You can see this in the ping example on https://github.com/zettio/weave/tree/master/weavedns

Comment: I just asked a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401418/docker-weave-and-weavedns-issues

Comment: Anyone has solution for this issue: ping the docker container from other host, but not resolve by its hostname ?  Also I faced this issue sometimes when i restart container