# Docker Weave and WeaveDNS issues

Tags: dns, docker, weave

I'm having an issue with setting up weaveDNS on a small weave network that I have running on my local machine.

For now the problem manifests itself in the fact that when I run 'weave status' I'm not seeing a DNS section in the output (as its suggested in the Troubleshooting section of http://docs.weave.works/weave/latest_release/weavedns.html).

I'm running 4 containers. `weave ps` output is:

```
c1d106ed5717 c2:ce:53:49:98:f6 10.0.1.12/24  
8f01765b2ba6 ba:2e:c3:4b:8f:8f 10.0.1.30/24  
0d824d914383 ae:95:28:db:95:18 10.0.1.11/24  
6cf985b91e9a 12:82:31:c2:b4:49 10.0.1.10/24  
b43f86e9fb51 d6:2e:d4:6a:09:dc **10.0.1.200/24**  
2847dd89e90d be:8b:d5:74:07:94
```

The highlighted container (10.0.1.200) is the weaveDNS container. The final container (2847dd89e90d) is the Weave router container.

I'm starting containers with:

```
sudo weave run --with-dns 10.0.1.30/24 -h service.weave.local --name service service_img_name
```

Does anyone have an idea why `weave status` is not showing a DNS section?
If you need me to give you additional info on the Weave setup, please let me know.

Comment: Same behavior on a Fedora 21 kernel 3.19.2 running in VMWare Fusion 7.1.1 with NAT networking.  I've used weavedns without issue on other non-virtualized servers (Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04) with no issue.  I can't find anything helpful in any weave status/ps/debug startup output.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a release version (0.9.0 at time of writing) of weave?

```
$ sudo weave version
weave script 0.9.0
weave router 0.9.0
weave DNS 0.9.0
weave tools 0.9.0
```

If so the problem is that the documentation tracks current master, not the latest release - inclusion of weaveDNS status output in `weave status` is a post-0.9.0 feature. I've raised [an issue](https://github.com/zettio/weave/issues/520) to support versioning of docs to avoid this problem in future.

Comment: Versioning the docs is a must. I'm totally lost trying to figure out what commands I should be using.